Alpharius as a captain of a customised chapter
Can I use Alpharius as a captain in a space marine chapter without being alpha legion?
I am making as space sharks successor chapter; I like the sound of the Carcharodons but want to make my own chapter.

Exactly which game and which edition are you playing? There is no datasheet for Alpharius in 40k proper, so the answer is "no". If you're playing Horus Heresy (either edition), then the Space Sharks don't exist as whatever their heritage, they're certainly post-Second Founding.

Yes.
As long as you are clear to your opponent as to what datasheet and loadout your models are, and they are roughly the same size, and on the same base, it's fine to use "different" models.
The resin "Horus Heresy Character Series" Alpharius miniature is on a 40mm base, which slots into a 60mm base diorama. A space marine captain uses a 40mm base, so that is fine. He is wielding a big spear and has a holstered plasma pistol, which fits the "Master Crafted Power Weapon and Plasma Pistol" loadout option of a Space Marine Captain.

Thank you so much
